# is it safe to use string hashcode as etag

Tags: java, jersey, probability

Given a  certain input parameter, for a rest api i want to use the hashcode as etag.
What is the probability that the json response has changed and the hashcode will be the same?

Alternatively is there a better way to do this?

```
@GET
    public Response getConfigurationForView(@PathParam("in1") String in1, @Context Request request) throws Exception {
        String jsonResponse = getJsonResponse(in1);
        EntityTag etag = new EntityTag(Integer.toString(in1.hashCode()) + "-" + Integer.toString(jsonResponse.hashCode()));
        ResponseBuilder builder = request.evaluatePreconditions(etag);


         if(builder == null){
             builder = Response.ok(jsonResponse, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
             builder.tag(etag);
         }

        return builder.build();
    }
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785091/consistency-of-hashcode-on-a-java-string

Comment: As i understand the quoted post is about if the hashcode of a string is the same across different versions of java. I am asking what the probability is that for two different strings i will get the same hash code.

Comment: Beware: hashcode can be negative. Sometimes the string shall not contain hyphens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you only have 4 billion possible hash codes for the whole variety of strings, there's a decent chance you'll eventually encounter ETag collisions.

Looking at how `String.hashCode()` is implemented:

```
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
```

-- you can even come up with possible collisions yourself. For instance, `""` (an empty string) and `"\0"` (the string containing only `\0` character) will give you the same `hashCode` of 0.

I would suggest you use a SHA1 hash (or MD5, but see these notes on [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770900) and [CPU running time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722943) first).

Provided you proceed with SHA1 hash, your code might look like this:

```
public static String calculateEtag(final String s) throws java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    final java.nio.ByteBuffer buf = java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(s);
    final java.security.MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    buf.mark();
    digest.update(buf);
    buf.reset();
    return String.format("W/\"%s\"", javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest.digest()));
}
```

This will produce the output identical of that of `sha1sum` utility.
You could use `BigInteger` to convert a byte buffer to a hex string as well:

```
new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16)
```

-- but `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary()` is several times faster.

Comment: We may use DigestUtils: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html in order to create md5 or sha1

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jdk8+ and Google Guava, you might try

```
final String myETag = ( (Set<Object>) this.setOfChangeableProperties ).stream()
  .filter( Objects::nonNull )
  .map( Objects::toString )
  .reduce( (a,b) -> a.concat(b) )
  .map( s -> Hashing.md5().hashUnencodedChars( s ).toString() )
  .orElse( "nothing of interest to hash!" )
```